# Why having problem with GDALRasterize() in C?

Tags: gdal, c, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to make raster file from a shapefile. I am trying to use GDALRasterize() function for it. But it is not recognizing GDALRasterize function ('GDALRasterize' was not declared in this scope). But I have included GDAL.h, cpl_port.h.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gdal.h>
#include <cpl_conv.h>
#include <cpl_port.h>

//main function
int main()
{   
char path1[200],path2[200],filename1[]="/inRasters/line.tif",filename2[]="/in_shapes/line.shp";
GDALDatasetH lineDS,lineDS_shp;

GDALAllRegister();

getcwd(path1, sizeof(path1));
strcpy(path2,path1);
strcat(path1,filename1);
strcat(path2,filename2);

lineDS_shp = GDALOpenEx(path2, GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL );
lineDS = GDALRasterize(path1,NULL,lineDS_shp,NULL,NULL);    

GDALClose(lineDS_shp);
GDALClose(lineDS);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDALRasterize defined in gdal_utils.h
See usage here: https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/apps/gdal_rasterize_bin.cpp

**since GDAL 2.1**

Comment: But my compiler is not detecting either gdal_utils.h or gdal_utils_priv.h header files. It is giving fatal error: (gdal_utils.h/gdal_utils_priv.h): no such file or directory compilation terminated.

Comment: This is only available in GDAL 2 (both method and header). Do you have compatible version of GDAL?

Comment: I have gdal 2.0.1, but I think that is not enough. May be gdal 2.1

Comment: Yes, in description of the method noted since GDAL 2.1 -  https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/apps/gdal_rasterize_lib.cpp. May be GDALRasterizeLayers you are looking for? See http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#adfe5e5d287d6c184aab03acbfa567cb1

Comment: yes, gdal2.1 works